# Upgrading from Angular 10 to 13 gives error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path_to_service' or its correponding type declarations

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an Angular App using [paper-dashboard template](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-dashboard-angular)
It has Angular version 10.0

I have now updated to Angular version 13, so am now using another template [WrapPixel](https://www.wrappixel.com/templates/adminpro-angular-lite/)

But I am getting an error  if I include the service reference in ts file as below

```
Error: src/app/about/about.component.ts:2:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/services/rate.service' or its corresponding type declarations.



import { RateService } from 'app/services/rate.service';
```

[image]

This is my file structure and RateService.

[image]

I've looked into different solutions googling given for error TS2307, but nothing worked for me & am not able to resolve my issue.

I am new to Angular can you please help me to resolve this.

**Update**

Since I was getting the issue with my application, I removed all my components and just added one model & one service file to template_code from [WrapPixel](https://www.wrappixel.com/templates/adminpro-angular-lite/) to narrow down the issue.
So now I have found out that if I add a reference to service file in component.ts it is throwing `error TS2307` else it compiles fine.

I am  new to Angular, so please guide me if I need to add any reference in any other component\module to resolve the issue.

Comment: Use relative path instead of absolute? or add src/

Comment: I am getting the error only when I compile `ng serve`. Are you suggesting still the absolute path is required?

Comment: Thanks @Vega changing the path `import { RateService } from '../services/rate.service';` compiles the app and able to execute.
Can you please add this as an answer, so that I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this

```
"paths": {
      "app/": ["/src/app/"]
}
```

to tsconfig.app.json resolved my issue while ng serve.

But the error message in vscode is didn't gone.
[image]

.

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/": ["/src/app/"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "../node_modules/@nebular/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../src/*.ts",
    "../src/**/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/@nebular/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true
  },
}
```